# MSVC10 SFINAE causing fatal error rather than substitution failure

Tags: templates, sfinae, c++11, visual-studio-2010

I've got a (relatively) brief code sample here.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> class function;
template<typename Ret> class function<Ret()> {
public:
    template<typename Func> function(Func f, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Ret, decltype(f())>::value, int>::type x = 0) {
    }
};
template<typename Ret, typename A1> class function<Ret(A1)> {
public:
    template<typename Func> function(Func f, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Ret, decltype(f(*((A1*)nullptr)))>::value, int>::type x = 0) {
    }
};

namespace lols {
    int x() { return 0; }
    int y(int) { return 0; }
}
void func(function<int()>) {}
void func(function<int(int)>) {}

int main() {
    func(&lols::x);
    func(&lols::y);
}
```

MSVC throws on this, saying that `type` is not a member of `enable_if<false, int>`, which is kind of the point. What I don't get is why this causes a fatal error instead of just a substitution failure- on GCC this code behaves exactly as expected and compiles cleanly.

Comment: They implemented SFIAFE by mistake :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) compiles and runs your code without complaint.

Comment: What version, which c++ stdlib?

Comment: I ran something very close to tip-of-trunk, along with libc++.

Comment: Also compiles fine in GCC 4.6.